# Particles invert

Tags: particles, weight-painting

I want create grass with hair method, but the object appear on opposite side of the emitter.

I already try too reverse face direction but it just make the reverse, particles outside, grass inside.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You tried inverting the faces after combing, right?

Comment: that what i did

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce it entirely, but if you alter your geometry too much, it's best to delete the particle edit progress and start over.

Comment: Ok thank you ! i'm gonna try